# Pass one to many table entity from View to Model in MVC3 to Update in DB

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am getting null values of Model on Controller when I submit Ajax.BeginForm form. Model have another model inside (one to many relationship)

Here is my Sample View code (removed unnecessary things)

```
 <table id="PageSortTable" class="travelads_business_rules" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr valign="bottom">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Rule Name</th>
        <th>Business</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Form</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Media</th>
        <th>InsertLoc</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Access</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="col_a">
                <span>@item.id</span>
            </td>
            <td class="col_b">
                <a href="@(Url.Action("EditTravelAdsRule", new { id = item.id }))">
                    <img alt="Edit" class="tableItemImage" src="../../Content/Images/Edit-icon.PNG" title="Edit" />
                </a><a href="@(Url.Action("DeleteTravelAdsRule", new { id = item.id }))">
                    <img alt="Delete" class="tableItemImage" src="../../Content/Images/delete-icon.PNG"
                        title="Delete" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col_c">
                <div class="tableButtonCell"><a href="#" onclick='DoExpandCollapsh("trMinimised@(item.id)")'>
                        <img alt="Details" class="tableItemImage" src="../../Content/Images/expand-icon.png"
                            title="Expand" /></a></div>
            </td>
            <td class="col_d"><span>@item.ad_rule_name</span></td>
            <td class="col_f"><span>@item.business</span></td>
            <td class="col_g"><span>@item.ad_region</span></td>
            <td class="col_h"><span>@item.ad_form</span></td>
            <td class="col_i"><span>@item.ad_company</span></td>
            <td class="col_j"><span>@item.ad_team</span></td>
            <td class="col_k"><span>@item.ad_language</span></td>
            <td class="col_l"><span>@item.ad_media_id</span></td>
            <td class="col_m"><span>@item.ad_insert_loc</span></td>
            <td class="col_n"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td class="col_o"><span>@item.access</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="minimised" id='trMinimised@(item.id)'>
            <td colspan="13">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SaveGroupMatchs", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "msgResult", LoadingElementId = "msgLoading" }, new { @id = "SaveForm"}))
                {  

                <div class="detail">
                    <div class="table_header">
                        <span class="col_a">Group</span> <span class="col_b">Group Scope</span> <span class="col_c">
                            Seq</span> <span class="col_d">&nbsp;</span> <span class="col_e">ID</span> <span
                                class="col_f">Match Location</span> <span class="col_g">Target Field</span>
                        <span class="col_h">Match Type</span> <span class="col_i">Set Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Loop for matches -->
                    <!-- start GROUP -->
                    <div class="group">
                        @foreach (var item1 in item.lstMatches)
                        {
                            <div id="rule@(item.id)_divRuleGroup_@(item1.match_group_num)">
                            <header id="header_rule_Group"><span class="col_a">@(item1.match_group_num)  </span><span class="col_b">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item1.match_group_scope, new SelectList((List<QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.clsGroupScope>)QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.General.GetALLGroupScope(), "GroupNum", "GroupScope", item1.match_group_num))
                                          </span></header>
                            <div class="match">
                                <span class="col_c">@(item1.match_group_seq) @Html.HiddenFor(model=>item1.match_group_seq) </span> <span class="col_d"><a href="#">
                                    <img src="../../Content/Images/delete-icon.png" width="17" height="17" border="0"
                                        title="delete" /></a> </span><span class="col_e">@(item1.match_id)
                                        </span><span class="col_f">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item1.match_loc, new SelectList((List<QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.clsMatchLocations>)QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.General.GetALLMatchLocations(), "MatchLocations", "MatchLocations", item1.match_loc))
                                        </span><span class="col_g">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item1.match_target_field, new SelectList((List<QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.clsTargetField>)QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.General.GetALTargetField(), "TargetField", "TargetField", item1.match_target_field))
                                        </span><span class="col_h">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item1.match_type, new SelectList((List<QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.clsMatchType>)QIOnlineMVC3.Helpers.General.GetALLMatchType(), "MatchTypeID", "MatchType", item1.match_type))
                                        </span><span class="col_i">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item1.match_set_name, new { @value = item1.match_set_name, @class="clsauto" })
                                           @* <input type="text" name="sets" id="sets" class="clsauto" style="width:200px;" value='@(item1.match_set_name)'/>*@
                                            </span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <!-- end MATCH -->
                        <div class="new">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="../../Content/Images/new-icon.png" width="17" height="17" border="0" alt="New Match" />New
                                Match</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end MATCH GROUP -->
                    <!-- END Loop of Matches -->
                    <div class="new new_group">
                        <img alt="" src="../../Content/Images/new-icon.png" width="17" height="17" border="0" />@Ajax.ActionLink("New Group", "GetGroupMatch", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "divNewGroup", HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter})
                        <div class="delete_group">
                            Delete Group ID:
                            <input type="text" id='txtdeleteGroupNo_@(item.id)' />
                            <input type="submit" id='btnDeleteGroup_@(item.id)' value="Delete Group" class="btn btn_delete" style="float: none;" onclick="return DeleteGroup(this);" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divNewGroup">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn_row">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn" value="Cancel" onclick='DoExpandCollapsh("trMinimised@(item.id)","main_collapsed@(item.id)","main_expanded@(item.id)")'/>
                        <input type="submit" name="btnSave" class="btn" value="Save" />
                        <a href="@(Url.Action("DeleteTravelAdsRule", new { id = item.id }))" class="btn btn_delete">
                            Delete Rule</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }

            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```

Here is my Controller Actions

```
  [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _SaveGroupMatchs(FormCollection fc, TravelAdsRulesMatchsGroups trmg)
    { 
   // trmg is null here... I  am getting form collection but its comma separated, very annoying to deal with that.
   }
```

Can anybody have Idea, how do I get Model values.

Here is my class information

Main class TravelAds - required to show mail records (grid)

TravelAdsRulesMatchsGroups  - First foreach loop class inside the table

MatchCollection - Second foreach loop class inside TravelAdsRulesMatchsGroups

I am trying to get TravelAdsRulesMatchsGroups object with values and with sub class (Match Collection) in controller, there should be anyway, I think.

Thanks in Advance
- Amit Prajapati

Comment: your code needs formatting man ! vry difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `foreach` loops that you wrote are killing everything. Please read about the standard conventions that you need to use for naming your input elements that the default model binder expects: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Now look at generated HTML source code of your page and more specifically the names of your input fields. What a mess, isn't it? Nothing matches what the default model binder expects. When you use expressions such as `model => item1.match_type` the name of the generated input field doesn't take into account the current navigational context of the complex property.

One possibility is to use editor templates instead of those foreach loops. It's the solution I recommend. I have written like gazillions of posts about them, just [Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=darin+dimitrov+editor+templates+asp.net+mvc+foreach+site%3ahttp://stackoverflow.com&oq=darin+dimitrov+editor+templates+asp.net+mvc+foreach+site%3ahttp://stackoverflow.com&gs_l=hp.3...2475.7013.1.7194.30.30.0.0.0.0.131.2830.20j10.30.0...0.0...1c.TtA2wHm0hbw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3d04e930a01db91d&biw=1600&bih=795).

Another possibility is to modify your models to use indexed collections and then use `for` loops instead of `foreach`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    ... some stuff ....

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].SomeProperty)

    @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].SomeCollectionProperty.Count; j++)
    {
        ... some stuff, ajax forms etc ....
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].SomeCollectionProperty[j].SomeOtherProperty)
    }
}
```

Notice how the lambda expressions used now includes not only the navigational property name but the index as well. This will allow for the helpers to generate proper names for the input fields.

Comment: Thanks for the very good answer, could you please tell me, how to just get the property in "for" loop, like <div id=@(item1.id)>....

Comment: I have shown exactly that in my answer: `x => x[i].SomeProperty` or for the inner loop: `x => x[i].SomeCollectionProperty[j].SomeOtherProperty`.

Comment: I don't want to set in Textbox, I want it to make dynamic ID of other controls...

Comment: What dynamic ID? In the example you have shown you have used `DropDownListFor`. So just replace my `TextBoxFor` with a `DropDownListFor` if that's what you wanna use.

Comment: @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{ <div id=x[0].id>
} -- not working

Comment: Of course that it is not working. There's no `x` variable in this scope. You should use `<div id="@(Model[i].id)">...</div>`.

Comment: Yeah, I understood you. Please be more specific when asking questions next time. So did my tip work?

Comment: I tried it, <div id="@(Model[0].id)">, It gives me an error "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expressions of type 'System.Collections.Generatic.IEnumeratble<my model class>', Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, apparently you didn't read my answer carefully. So I repeat it here once again: `Another possibility is to modify your models to use indexed collections and then use for loops instead of foreach:`. I said that you need to use **indexed collections** for this to work. Right now you are using `IEnumerable<my model class>` which obviously cannot be accessed by index. For example you could work with `IList<my model type>` or directly an array `my model type[]` (in which case use `.Length` instead of `.Count`).

Comment: I am trying with IList collection and Now It is <div id="@(Model[0].id)"> working

Comment: That's great. Is there something else you would like to ask about?

Comment: I hope, I will get filled Model object with values in controller, not like previous.. Let me try to bind all controls and hit submit button... Thank you very much Darin, learnt a new thing..

Comment: Sorry, Not working, still getting null Model values at controller side. I have Converted my all code with for loops .....

Comment: Your controller action must take an `IList<your model>` as parameter. It is this parameter that will get bound.